Movie in late 90s featuring radio telescopes and man getting frozen and arm cut off
For years I thought this movie I had seem playing on a TV in the electronics department of a store when I was a kid was "Contact", because of the telescopes and alien vibe it gave off, but I recently watched Contact and it wasn't it.
Specifically the scene in question featured a man with glasses standing in the middle of a whirling vortex, debris surrounding him as someone (the protagonist I assume) tries to stop him. Somehow he gets frozen solid, and his rival breaks his arm off and it shatters on the ground. The rival then climbs out to reveal they are standing in the middle of the dish of a huge telescope, and I believe there was a young black kid yelling and throwing a bag to them. I don't recall what the rival looked like at all. 

You're definitely looking for the 1996 film The Arrival.
It's an interesting film that features the search for Alien life. There are some good conspiracy themes following Charlie Sheen's character. It features everything you describe in the question which is at the very end of the film, so please note the spoiler warning below.
Trailer:



Warning Spoiler:

Phil and his agents ram down the door to the satellite control room with a van, but Zane freezes them with liquid nitrogen vapors. As he works to free the tape stuck in Phil's frozen jacket, one of the agents drops a sphere which starts to form another singularity in the room. Phil begins to defrost, and tries to grab Zane's arm, but Zane smashes off Phil's arm with a fire axe. Zane and Char escape through the satellite's optical path, exiting safely onto the collapsed dish before the device implodes most of the satellite dish's base. In the distance they see Kiki, and Zane tells him to tell the aliens that he will soon broadcast this tape; they watch as Kiki runs off. In the film's epilogue, Zane's conversation with Phil is broadcast across the globe.


